# how to view system startup and shutdown information

Tags: shutdown

ever since i repartitioned my logical drive using "Disks" application in ubuntu 13.10, i keep on getting some error messages at system startup and shutdown. but those are too fast to read. also, now when i shutdown my system, it doesn't shuts down but instead goes into a halt state.

is there any way to properly read those error messages?
does the log file records them?
if yes, what keywords should i search for to locate those events and the information regarding them in the log file?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
shell> dmesg | less
```

will do the job.

Comment: it says no 'shell' command found.

Comment: You need to use `dmesg | less` in a terminal (without 'shell>'). Hope you have already figured it out.